# Add event or task to calendar in JAVA - Netbeans

Tags: java, events, netbeans, calendar

Is there a library or a way to add events to a Calendar, in the style of google calendar? I have searched but have only found to select the date, but not to assign an event or task to a specific date in the Calendar using Netbeans for Desktop App.

Comment: There is no calendar like this in J2SE. But if you went to GitHub you might be able to find one there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the standard `Calendar` class (`java.util.Calendar`) is misleading - the class is not a calendar as we are used to, it does **not** store *appointments*, events or that like - it is more like an instant in time.

It is normally used to *work* with the different date/time fields like Hour, Day, Month, ... 
For details, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html):

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next week.
> ...